# Cannot load slick-carousel in angular 4 : Cannot load css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angular

I am using slick-carousel in angular 4 [slick-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/slick-carousel)

In my home.component.html

```
<div class="list-books" *ngIf="results?.length > 0">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6" *ngFor="let item of results;let i=index">
    <a>
      <div class="mt-card-item">
        <div class="mt-card-content">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <span>{{item.Name}}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row" >
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <span>{{item.Address}}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
              <span class="mt-card-name">{{item.Telephone}}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Inside my home.component.ts

```
  $('.list-books').slick({
            dots: false,
            infinite: false,
            speed: 300,
            fade: false,
            slidesToShow: 4,
            slidesToScroll: 4,
            responsive: [
                {
                    breakpoint: 1024,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 3,
                        slidesToScroll: 1,
                        infinite: true,
                        dots: true
                    }
                },
                {
                    breakpoint: 600,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 2,
                        slidesToScroll: 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    breakpoint: 480,
                    settings: {
                        slidesToShow: 1,
                        slidesToScroll: 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
```

The variable *results* holds the data to be filled in by the carousel. When the component loads I can se the data but could not load the css and breaks the UI. It looks the data comes first but cant load the css cannot figure it out

I have also added the css in my index.html and slick.min.js in my angular.json

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />
```

```
 "node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js"
```

Any idea about what could be done. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to add on I tried adding the code to initialize the carousel both in ngOnInit() and constructor()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here [try](https://github.com/vasyabigi/angular-slick/issues/2)  Try to add a timeout for your init()

```
setTimeout(() => { //you slick-carousel init code }, 1000);
```

In angular js version it worked as suggested by Nick njj

Comment: This is not an answer, please use the comments for sentences like this one

Comment: I have checked I am able to get the data but whole carousel breaks, all items in a vertical line.

Comment: Could you try including the css `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />` in you angular-cli. Let me know

Comment: I tried to include both the script and css in angular-cli but doesn't look like its working.

Comment: Here [try](https://github.com/vasyabigi/angular-slick/issues/2)
Try to add a timeout for your init()
`setTimeout(() => {
}, 1000);
`
In angular js version it worked as suggested by Nick njj.

Comment: It works!!! I added 
` setTimeout(() => {
  this.initSlickCarousel();
  }, 100);`
Thanks a lot!!! @77792

Comment: Great @user3239090!! Please mark the answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

In angular.json it has a section like:

```
"styles": [
    "//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.css",
  ],
```

Or if you want add your src/style.css

```
@import "//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.css";
```

And other hand I have found a working example on stackBlitz
[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slick-carousel)